Use the aliased version of a bash command from within script
My .bash_aliases (loaded from .bashrc) defines an alias for tmux like this:
alias tmux='tmux -f /home/myuser/.config/tmux/tmux.conf -L mysocket'

Now I have a script tmux-sessionizer.sh that I execute (not source) as part of a keymap in nvim. The script invokes tmux:
...
if [[ -z $TMUX ]] && [[ -z $tmux_running ]]; then
    tmux new-session -s $selected_name -c $selected
    exit 0
fi
...

However the problem is that this tmux invocation will not use my alias, since aliases are not loaded when a bash script is executed (this is known). This means that the sessionizer script wont use my socket that I always provide with the -L flag in the alias. But if it doesn't use this socket then it won't find the session. The question is how do I work around this?

Use a function instead? tmux(){ command tmux -f /home/myuser/.config/tmux/tmux.conf -L mysocket "$@"; }

The problem is not to load the aliases - you are free to load them from your script, if you want to - but to enable alias expansion. This has to be turned on explicitly. It is disabled, since virtually nobody wants to use an alias in a script.

tmux will already look for a configuration file at ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf; why specify it explicitly?
